# Como fechar o stage raiz ao abrir um novo no javafx?

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar um botão, que, ao clicar, abra outra tela.

Porém, ao abrir a segunda tela ele mantém a primeira.

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que a primeira tela seja fechada e a segunda seja aberta ao clicar no botão.

[image]

**Evento do botão:**

[image]

**Tela inicial:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dar um close() na primeira janela antes de chamar a outra não resolve?

Comment: da um erro quando eu tento usar this.close();
http://prntscr.com/mnynrv